# RSpec test class from within a module without the actual file

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have a module for creating parts (products) in my store called `ErpPartsService::Builder` and withing the module I have built a helper class `CategoryByLauberIdFetcher` that I just use internally within the module, not anywhere else. I have it inside the file `app/services/erp_parts_service/builder.rb`.

Here's my code:

```
module ErpPartsService
  class CategoryByLauberIdFetcher < Service # This is the helper class that I want to test.
    def initialize(...)
      ...
    end

    def call(lauber_id:)
      ...
    end
  end

  class Builder < Service
    def initialize(
      category_by_lauber_id: CategoryByLauberIdFetcher
    )
      @category_by_lauber_id = category_by_lauber_id
    end

    def call(...)
      ...
    end

    private

    def get_category_by_lauber_id(id)
      @category_by_lauber_id.call(lauber_id: id)
    end
  end
end
```

I wrote tests for `CategoryByLauberIdFetcher` within `spec/services/erp_parts_service/category_by_lauber_id_fetcher_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe ErpPartsService::CategoryByLauberIdFetcher do
  it '...' do
    ...
  end
end
```

When I run them I get:

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant ErpPartsService::CategoryByLauberIdFetcher
```

I wrote tests for `Builder` class within
`spec/services/erp_parts_service/builder_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe ErpPartsService::Builder do
  it '...' do
    ...
  end
end
```

And they work fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an autoloader issue:

1. Seeing the constant `ErpPartsService::Builder` the autoloader expects a file `erp_parts_service/builder.rb` and it finds it... but
2. Seeing `ErpPartsService::CategoryByLauberIdFetcher` autoloader tries to find `erp_parts_service/category_by_lauber_id_fetcher.rb` and fails, because definition of this class is in `erp_parts_service/builder.rb`

Add `require` to explicitly load the file containing the class you're trying to test.

```
require 'erp_parts_service/builder.rb'
RSpec.describe ErpPartsService::CategoryByLauberIdFetcher do
  it '...' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Or (better yet) put each class in a separate file and stick to the convention. Not only the autoloader, but other people joining your project would look for this class in a file that doesn't exist.

I know you've mentioned that you want to use this class only inside your module, but that's not the way to make it "private". You just made it annoying to use it instead of protecting it from being used.

Comment: Thanx that worked. Note, I use this class only inside this module and I don't think I've made it "annoying to use"...Thanx anyway.

Comment: Agree to disagree, your problems are a proof that the way it's organized now is confusing for people and the autoloader. And the truth is: you don't use it only inside this module, you're using it in the specs separately. I'm not sure if this is aparticular code smell, but it feels like one. Anyway it's just a suggestion, I'm glad I could help with the original problem. Cheers!